# WPF 3D object rotating continuously

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, rotation, transform

I am using SplineRotation3DKeyFrame to rotate my 3D object continuously.
But the behavior is somehow queer:
1. there must be two SplineRotation3DKeyFrame inside Rotation3DAnimationUsingKeyFrames, or there will be not animation.
2. it seems the rotation is not continuous. there is always an abrupt movement every period.

And I want to make it rotate at some speed, for example 30 round per minute.

Could any give me some advice how to setup the animation code?

Thanks in advance.

Ting

here is my code (excluding 3D data)

```
             Storyboard.TargetName="World"
             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ModelVisual3D.Transform).(Transform3DGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform3D.Rotation)"
            Duration="00:00:02"
            AutoReverse="False">

            <SplineRotation3DKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02">
                <SplineRotation3DKeyFrame.Value >
                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="180" Axis="0,0,1"/>
                </SplineRotation3DKeyFrame.Value>
            </SplineRotation3DKeyFrame>
            <SplineRotation3DKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:04">
                <SplineRotation3DKeyFrame.Value>
                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="359" Axis="0,0,1"/>
                </SplineRotation3DKeyFrame.Value>
            </SplineRotation3DKeyFrame>
        </Rotation3DAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource RotateStoryboard}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>


<Grid>
    <Viewport3D ClipToBounds="True" Margin="21,15,10,28">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <OrthographicCamera FarPlaneDistance="291.04190202230194" LookDirection="0,-30,0" NearPlaneDistance="0.1" Position="0,30,0" UpDirection="0,0,-1" Width="50"/>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <ModelVisual3D x:Name="World">

    <ModelVisual3D.Transform> <!-- tinger -->
        <Transform3DGroup>
            <RotateTransform3D/>
        </Transform3DGroup>
    </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
```

Comment: is my question too naive? or simple?  Surely I am new to WPF. I am in the way to try to produce a simple WPF control that could display a rotating part of our equipment: I borrow the 3D data from the design staff, and put it to the WPF control and animate it.